# How to import lots of data into matlab from a spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, matlab, import

I have an excel spreadsheet with lots of data that I want to import into matlab.

```
filename = 'for_matlab.xlsx';
sheet = (13*2)+ 1;
xlRange = 'A1:G6';
all_data = {'one_a', 'one_b', 'two_a', 'two_b', 'three_a', 'three_b', 'four_a', 'four_b', 'five_a', 'five_b', 'six_a', 'six_b', 'seven_a', 'seven_b', 'eight_a', 'eight_b', 'nine_a', 'nine_b', 'ten_a', 'ten_b', 'eleven_a', 'eleven_b', 'twelve_a', 'twelve_b', 'thirteen_a', 'thirteen_b', 'fourteen_a'};

%read data from excel spreadsheet
for i=1:sheet,
    all_data{i} = xlsread(filename, sheet, xlRange);
end
```

Each element of the 'all_data' vector has a corresponding matrix in separate excel sheet. The code above imports the last matrix only into all of the variables. Could somebody tell me how to get it so I can import these matrices into individual matlab variables (without calling the xlsread function 28 times)?

Answer (score 0):

You define a loop using `i` but then put `sheet` in the actual `xlsread` call, which will just make it read repeatedly from the same sheet (the value of the variable `sheet` is not changing).  Also not sure whether you intend to somehow save the contents of `all_data`, as written there's no point in defining it that way as it will just be overwritten.

There are two ways of specifying the sheet using `xlsread`.

1) Using a number. If you intended this then:

```
all_data{i} = xlsread(filename, i, xlRange);
```

2) Using the name of the sheet. If you intended this and the contents of `all_data` are the names of sheets, then:

```
data{i} = xlsread(filename, all_data{i}, xlRange); %avoiding overwriting
```